# Running web-application on Heroku

Tags: java, heroku

When I'm trying to run my Play! application on Herocu I have a message that I should run it with "play -DapplyEvolutions.default=true" command. But how can I do it?

Now what I'm doing is pushing to my webapp to heroku and operate with commands: "heroku ps" and "heroku logs". The last one gives me error details. How can I run application on heroku remotely?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this Play 2?  If so you will need a `Procfile` containing:

```
web: target/start -Dhttp.port=$PORT -DapplyEvolutions.default=true -Ddb.default.driver=org.postgresql.Driver -Ddb.default.url=$DATABASE_URL
```